# How do I calculate $ \int_{1}^{3} x/(2-x) \;\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

$ \int_{1}^{3} \frac{x}{2-x} \;\mathrm{d}x$

$ \int_{1}^{2} \frac{x}{2-x} \;\mathrm{d}x$ + $ \int_{2}^{3} \frac{x}{2-x} \;\mathrm{d}x$

$u = 2-x$

$\lim_{e\to0} \left[  \int_{-e}^{1} \frac{2-u}{u} \;\mathrm{d}u +  \int_{-1}^{e} \frac{2-u}{u} \;\mathrm{d}u \right]$

No matter what I do this is giving me 0, but the answer is -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral does not converge, but the Cauchy-Principal value does.

$$\begin{align}
PV\int_1^3\frac{x}{2-x}dx&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\int_1^{2-\epsilon}\frac{x}{2-x}dx+\int_{2+\epsilon}^{3}\frac{x}{2-x}dx\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\left .(2\log|2-x|-x)\right|_{1}^{2-\epsilon}+\left .(2\log|2-x|-x)\right|_{2+\epsilon}^{3}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left((\epsilon-1)+2\log|\epsilon|+(\epsilon-1)+2\log|1/\epsilon|\right)\\\\
&=-2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

I guess from the start of your work that you are using the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) to work around the improperness of the integrals.  In that case, you've got the right idea.  After substituting $u=2-x$, $du =-dx$, you have
$$
   \int_1^3 \frac{x}{2-x}\,dx = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2-u}{u}\,du = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2}{u}\,du - \int_{-1}^1 1 \,du
$$
Now show that the PV of $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{2}{u}\,du$ is zero and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\begin{align*}
\frac x{2-x} &= \frac x2\left(\frac1{1-\frac12x}\right)\\
&= \frac x2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^n x^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{n+1} x^{n+1}\\
\end{align*}$$
So by monotone convergence,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_1^3 \frac x{2-x}\mathsf dx &= \int_1^3\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{n+1} x^{n+1}\right)\mathsf dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( \int_1^3 \left(\frac12\right)^{n+1}x^{n+1}\mathsf dx\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{n+1}\left[\frac1{n+2}x^{n+2}\right]_1^3\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n+2}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+1}(3^{n+2} - 1)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2(n+2)}\left(\left(\frac32\right)^{n+2}-1\right)\\
\end{align*}$$
By the ratio test,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{\frac1{2(n+3)} \left( \left(\frac32\right)^{n+3}-1\right)}{\frac1{2(n+2)} \left( \left(\frac32\right)^{n+2}-1\right)}\\
&= \frac{\frac32(n+2)\left( \left(\frac32\right)^{n+3}-1\right)}{(n+3)\left( \left(\frac32\right)^{n+3}-\frac32\right)}\\
&= \frac{3(n+2)}{2(n+3)}\left(1 + \frac{1}{2\left(\frac32\right)^{n+3}-\frac32} \right)\\
&= \frac{3(n+2)}{2(n+3)}\left(1 + \frac{1}{3\left(\frac32\right)^{n+2}-1} \right)\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac32>1.
\end{align*}$$
Hence the integral doesn't converge.